# How to Call a Generic Method using "Expression.Parameter" and "Expression.Call" APIs

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

Using the **Expression Tree API** I want to generate code for code that looks like this:

```
FieldInfo enumFieldInfo = enumFieldInfoSet.SingleOrDefault(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.Name == enumName);
```

I have written this code but it's not working:

```
var enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);
var enumerableGenericType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(FieldInfo));
var predicateGenericType =  typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<FieldInfo, bool>));

ParameterExpression fieldInfoSource = Expression.Parameter(enumerableGenericType, "fieldInfoSource");
ParameterExpression predicateSource = Expression.Parameter(predicateGenericType, "funcPredicateOnFieldInfo");

var arrayOfTypes = new Type[] { enumerableGenericType, predicateGenericType };

MethodCallExpression SingleOrDefaultMethodCall = Expression.Call(enumerableType, "SingleOrDefault",arrayOfTypes, fieldInfoSource, predicateSource);
```

Here is the runtime error: No generic method 'SingleOrDefault' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

I have tried a number of combinations of type coercion but still have not stumbled on the right combination. I know that the SingleOrDefault is an Extension method on the Enumerable class and that it needs two parameters; I've look at the code via the debugger and have written to code inspect its properties at run-time; what am I missing.

Comment: To bring a bit more light on the problem I think it is straight forward to use the Expression API to generate code where a single or a simple type is required in the parameter list; however, I have not seen code yet the demonstrates how to call a method that takes **Func<,>** as a parameter. Yikes, I think I may have just discovered the error: **Func<,>**.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` have only one generic parameter, by you supply `arrayOfTypes` with two types, also your `predicateGenericType` is `Func<Func<FieldInfo, bool>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `Expression.Call` overload which takes a type, and for a static method you need an overload with `MethodInfo`.

```
void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<FieldInfo>, Func<FieldInfo,bool>, FieldInfo>> singleOrDefaultExpr = (l,p) => l.SingleOrDefault(p);
    var callSource = (MethodCallExpression)singleOrDefaultExpr.Body;

    var method = callSource.Method;

    var collectionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<FieldInfo>), "enumFieldInfoSet");
    var enumNamePredicateParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Func<FieldInfo,bool>), "enumNamePredicate");

    var body = Expression.Call(method, collectionParameter, enumNamePredicateParameter);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<FieldInfo>, Func<FieldInfo, bool>, FieldInfo>>(body, collectionParameter, enumNamePredicateParameter);
    var f = lambda.Compile();

    Console.WriteLine(f(typeof(Apple).GetFields(), fi => fi.Name == "color").Name);
}

class Apple
{
    public string color;
}
```

Also, you can use another method to find the required MethodInfo:

```
var method = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "SingleOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {typeof(FieldInfo)});
```

UPDATE:

There is actually a simpler method, and you were on the right track, but your code had en error.

```
var collectionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<FieldInfo>), "enumFieldInfoSet");
var enumNamePredicateParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Func<FieldInfo,bool>), "enumNamePredicate");
var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "SingleOrDefault", new[] { typeof(FieldInfo)}, collectionParameter, enumNamePredicateParameter);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<FieldInfo>, Func<FieldInfo, bool>, FieldInfo>>(body, collectionParameter, enumNamePredicateParameter);
```

The problem was that SingleOrDefault has only one *generic type parameter*: 'FieldInfo' in this case:

```
SingleOrDefault<FieldInfo>(....
```

Don't mix it up with the *method parameters*, there are two of them:

```
SingleOrDefault<GenericParameter>(
    this IEnumerable<GenericParameter> firstMethodParameter,
    Func<GenericParameter, bool> secondMethodParameter
)
```

Comment: *SignleOrDefault does take two parameters*, but only one generic parameter. Third argument in `Expression.Call` is generic parameters, not types of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the input George; I can see where I made the mistake providing input to the Expression.Call method. However your answer did not help me in the way of "Why does the "Call" API behave this way. The SignleOrDefault does take two parameters but we only need to pass it one Generic Type parameter. That confused me in just how use the API. I re-coded so that it was clear to me; I'll supply the code later on today (11/12/2015).

Comment: Yep - that's what I did; thanks @PetSerAI. This is where I find the MSDN documentation lacking. I Can figure it out but it can take a lot of time. I documented my research in an answer I provided.

Answer (score 1):

George did a great job in getting me on the right track and did provide me a partial answer; I re-fashion my code so that is was clear to me. This is an example of code that I wanted to machine generate in testing our Meta-programming runtime. I am providing more code than is necessary for the specific problem but I wanted the others to see the greater context.

```
// Code to Generate Enum Field Metadata ...

string enumName   = Enum.GetName(theEnumType, theOrdinalEnumValue);
Array  enumValues = Enum.GetValues(theEnumType);
object enumValue  = enumValues.GetValue(theOrdinalEnumValue);
object enumObject = Enum.ToObject(theEnumType, theOrdinalEnumValue);

// Create Local variables of the types targeted for assignment expressions that we will make in the generated code

var enumVariables = Expression.RuntimeVariables(Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "gcEnumName"),
                                                Expression.Variable(typeof(Array), "gcEnumValues"),
                                                Expression.Variable(typeof(object), "gcEnumValue"),
                                                Expression.Variable(theEnumType, "gcEnumObject"),
                                                Expression.Variable(typeof(FieldInfo), "gcFieldInfoOnEnum"));

// Setup the Input Parameters for calls into Enum and Array Types in preperation for Assignments

ParameterExpression theInputOfEnumType     = Expression.Variable(typeof(Type), "theInputOfEnumType");
ParameterExpression theEnumFieldNameValue  = Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "theEnumFieldNameValue");
ParameterExpression aEnumObjectIndexValue  = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "aEnumObjectIndexValue");
ParameterExpression anArrayOfEnumObjects   = Expression.Variable(typeof(Array), "anArrayOfEnumObjects");
ParameterExpression anEnumerableObject     = Expression.Variable(typeof(Enumerable), "anEnumerableObject");
ParameterExpression directEnumTypeResolved = Expression.Variable(theEnumType, "directEnumTypeResolved");
ParameterExpression fieldInfoOnEnum        = Expression.Variable(typeof(FieldInfo), "fieldInfoOnEnum");

var fieldInfoEnumerableRepresentation = typeof(Enumerable);
```

In perpetration of making calls to "Expression.Call" we need to get some MethodInfo data

```
// We need to generate MethodInfo on the Methods we want to call in the generated code. This is metadata
// we need to call the Expression.Call API.

MethodInfo enumGetNameMethodInfo   = enumMetadata.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "GetName");
MethodInfo enumGetValuesMethodInfo = enumMetadata.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "GetValues");

MethodInfo enumGetValueMethodInfo  = arraryMetadata.GetMethods()
  .FirstOrDefault(methodInfo => (methodInfo.Name == "GetValue") && methodInfo.GetParameters().Any(param =>param.ParameterType == typeof(int)));
MethodInfo enumToObjectMethodInfo  = enumMetadata.GetMethods()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "ToObject");

// We know that there exist a number of polymorphic instances of the "SingleOrDefault" Extension method
// so we use the name of the parameter named "predicate" to locate our method. **FYI Can't use the MethodInfo data in a call to Expression.Call - It's a generic definition**.

MethodInfo enumerableSingleOrDefaultInfo = fieldInfoEnumerableRepresentation.GetMethods()
  .FirstOrDefault(methodInfo => (methodInfo.Name == "SingleOrDefault") &&
                                 methodInfo.GetParameters()
                                   .Any(param => param.Name == "predicate"));
```

Here is the final code that works in making a call to a Generic Method:

```
// An approach to setup a Generic method call that will be used in an Expression.Assign call

// I decompose this code so for debugging purposes

// I create the "inputOfTSourceType" as a Generic Type because in the Definition of "SingleOrDefault" method there is only one Generic Parameter;
// also, take special note that in the assemblage of Expression.Call methods any of the methods that take a MethodInfo instance you can't pass in
// a "Generic" method definition. If you take a look at the code that is called it will throw and exception if it detects the IsGenericMethodDefinition
// flag is true.
var inputOfTSourceType  = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(FieldInfo));  // This is the type on the "source" TSource parameter
var predicateOfFuncType = typeof(Func<FieldInfo, bool>);   // This is the type on the "predicate" parameter
// Take note there that we only define one(1) type here ("inputParameterType"); this is the type we wish apply to the Generic Type TSource
// declaration: public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
var inputParameterType  = new[] {typeof(FieldInfo)};       // This is the type we must match to "source" parameter

// The "SingleOrDefault" method can take two parameters and in this case I need to pass in a lambda expression as the predicate.
// Se we need two parameters. 

ParameterExpression fieldInfoSource = Expression.Parameter(inputOfTSourceType, "fieldInfoSource");           // This is: this IEnumerable<TSource>
ParameterExpression predicateSource = Expression.Parameter(predicateOfFuncType, "funcPredicateOnFieldInfo"); // This is: Func<TSource, bool> predicate

 MethodCallExpression SingleOrDefaultMethodCall = 
     Expression.Call(fieldInfoEnumerableRepresentation, // This is the Object Instance for which the 
                     "SingleOrDefault", // The Name of the Generic Method
                     inputParameterType, // The Generic Type
                     fieldInfoSource,    // this is the "this" source parameter
                     predicateSource);   // this the "predicate" parameter

 Expression localEnumNameAssignment =
   Expression.Assign(enumVariables.Variables[0], EnumGetNameMethodCall);
 Expression localEnumObjectsAssignment =
   Expression.Assign(enumVariables.Variables[1], EnumGetValauesMethodCall);
 Expression localEnumObjectAssignment =
   Expression.Assign(enumVariables.Variables[2], ArrayGetValueMethodCall);
 Expression localEnumTypeAssignment = 
   Expression.Assign(enumVariables.Variables[3], Expression.Convert(EnumToObjectMethodCall, theEnumType));
 Expression localFieldInfoAssignment =
   Expression.Assign(enumVariables.Variables[4], Expression.Convert(SingleOrDefaultMethodCall, typeof(FieldInfo)));

 BlockExpression blockExpression =
   Expression.Block(enumVariables, 
   localEnumNameAssignment, 
   localEnumObjectsAssignment, 
   localEnumObjectAssignment, 
   localEnumTypeAssignment, 
   localFieldInfoAssignment, 
   enumTypeToReturn);
```

Here's the generated code:

```
$gcEnumName = .Call System.Enum.GetName(
   $theInputOfEnumType, $gcEnumName = (System.String)$theEnumFieldNameValue)

$gcEnumValues = .Call System.Enum.GetValues($theInputOfEnumType)

$gcEnumValue = .Call $anArrayOfEnumObjects.GetValue((System.Int32)  $theOrdinalEnumValue)

$gcEnumObject = (WorkflowMessagingCommands).Call System.Enum.ToObject(
   $theInputOfEnumType,
   (System.Object)$theEnumInstance)

// Here is the generated code to call "SignleOrDefault"
$gcFieldInfoOnEnum = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(
    $thisSourceType,
    $predciateType)
```

Comment: what is the fieldInfoEnumerableRepresentation? without it the answer is incomplete

Comment: Yikes! an oversight on my part; I made an error in copying the code. Here's the missing code fragment: 

    var fieldInfoEnumerableRepresentation = typeof(Enumerable);

Comment: It has come to my attention that some may want to use this code to test with; I have only provided partial code so parts of it may not work. The code is part of an extensive codebase designed to test our Meta-programming runtime. I will post the working parts of code online so that others can play.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure that providing so much context serves the purpose of answering the original question better?

Comment: Maybe the piece of code you are working at worth a github project and a nuget package, but it would only entangle a solution to the original problem

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy thank you for you're helpful comments and insights; as a researcher and developer I can be overly robost at times as I get excited about my learnings and sharing. You and PetSerAI helped me to solve the problem and I wanted to provide a greater context to what I was asking. I will post a small project via GitHub.I will be more abrided in future post.